# Create a variable that can help me distinguish within group changes

Tags: r, syntax, data-analysis

I have the following data. And I want to make variable 1 and variable 2. Please see this png and you will see the data I have and what I want to make
[image: data Wanted]

I want to use R such that I can make Variable wanted 1, which is creating a group variable for every time the variable "input" shows up and is not empty (as seen in sample picture). I then want to use Dplyr to then create the Variable 2, which is basically taking the differences within groups. I think I can do that with the following

```
df %>% group_by(Group, variable wanted 1) %>% mutate(variable2 = diff(df, lag=1))
```

But as you can see, I am having trouble making the variable "Variable wanted 1". I hope I can explain myself adequately, and if not I would be happy to edit. Thank you for your help!

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3), Output = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 1, 4, 6, 8), 
    Input = c(NA, "a", NA, "b", NA, "a", NA, "b", NA, "c", NA, 
    "a", NA, "b")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Comment: Please don't post code/data as an image, it breaks screen-readers and we cannot use it to attempt your code. Please just post the data using `dput(x)` (or `dput(head(x))` if it is large-ish).

Comment: I made dataframe from your image. It would be appreciated if you share data using `dput`, not an imange.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your explanation of the problem using `fill` and `group_by` you can do -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  fill(Input, .direction = 'up') %>%
  mutate(result1 = match(Input, unique(Input))) %>%
  group_by(Group, result1) %>%
  mutate(result2 = lag(result1)) %>%
  ungroup

#   Group Output Input result1 result2
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <int>   <int>
# 1     1      2 a           1      NA
# 2     1      3 a           1       1
# 3     1      4 b           2      NA
# 4     1      5 b           2       2
# 5     2      3 a           1      NA
# 6     2      4 a           1       1
# 7     2      6 b           2      NA
# 8     2      7 b           2       2
# 9     2      9 c           3      NA
#10     2     10 c           3       3
#11     3      1 a           1      NA
#12     3      4 a           1       1
#13     3      6 b           2      NA
#14     3      8 b           2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(var_1 = rep(1:(n()/2), each = 2) ) %>%
  mutate(var_2 = ifelse(is.na(Input), "NA", Output - lag(Output, 1) ))

   Group Output Input var_1 var_2
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr>
 1     1      2 NA        1 NA   
 2     1      3 a         1 1    
 3     1      4 NA        2 NA   
 4     1      5 b         2 1    
 5     2      3 NA        1 NA   
 6     2      4 a         1 1    
 7     2      6 NA        2 NA   
 8     2      7 b         2 1    
 9     2      9 NA        3 NA   
10     2     10 c         3 1    
11     3      1 NA        1 NA   
12     3      4 a         1 3    
13     3      6 NA        2 NA   
14     3      8 b         2 2
```